# opengl (python) Camera rotate vs Cube Rotate gluLookAt() 's position in display code

Tags: python, opengl, opengl-compat

This code is a display part.

```py
def display(self):
    
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        if (self.axis == 0):
            glRotatef(self.pitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)      
        elif (self.axis == 1):
            glRotatef(self.yaw, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        elif (self.axis == 2):
            glRotatef(self.roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        
        
        self.colorcube()
        glFlush()
        glutSwapBuffers()
```

) figured it out that cube rotates when I put the code `gluLookAt()` before `glRotate()` and camera rotates when I put the code `gluLookAt()` after `glRotate()`.
but I don't know why. why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is a state engine. The current transformation matrix is a global state. Both functions `gluLookAt` and `glRotatef` define a matrix and multiply the current transformation matrix with the new defined matrix. The matrix multiplication is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), the order matters:

```
matrix1 * matrix2 != matrix2 * matrix1
```

Therfore:

```py
gluLookAt(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
glRotatef(self.pitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

is not the same as

```py
glRotatef(self.pitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
gluLookAt(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

You have to care about the order.